# Monitoring for std container resizing

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I am working on a high performance code base that is suffering from some performance problems due to container resizing. Inspecting throughput or latency over time shows a pattern in which exponentially increasing latency spikes are separated by exponentially increasing periods of time, suggestive of the doubling in size of containers as capacity increases.

I am having a difficult time tracking down which container is growing by manually searching through the code, and was hoping to track the container reservation with gdb.

Is there a breakpoint (or multiple breakpoints) I can set so that gdb will stop execution if a container reserves more space? I am unsure if the container is a vector, map, or set, so if all three rely on the same underlying call to resize, that might be best. Otherwise, I am happy to set multiple breakpoints.

Comment: If there is no other dynamic allocation, you could set a break point on `operator new`. But if there are many other dynamic allocations unrelated to this problem it might be too noisy.

Comment: The best thing is to step though the code when you know its going to resize (e.g. the first time you add an element) add add a breakpoint when you reach the resizing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a breakpoint (or multiple breakpoints) I can set so that gdb will stop execution if a container reserves more space?

No: vector, map and set do not share a common `resize` (except that all eventually get into `::operator new`).

You could set a conditional `::operator new` breakpoint for reasonably large size, and see where that's getting called from.

> suggestive of the doubling in size of containers as capacity increases.

Note that only `vector` does that, so setting a breakpoint on `std::vector...::_M_allocate` (for `libstdc++`) is probably a good starting point.